# How to get nic card name

Tags: c#, windows-server-2008-r2, ethernet, nic

Anybody knows how to get nic card name

when I do ipconfig/all
I can get this

```
Ethernet adapter XC99HT:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : xx.xx.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : HP NC382i DP Multifunction Gigabit Server
 Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : F4-CE-46-94-E8-B0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 177.77.153.48(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 177.77.153.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 177.77.124.129
                                       177.77.124.130
   Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 177.77.124.129
   Secondary WINS Server . . . . . . : 177.77.124.130
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

would like to get "HP NC382i DP Multifunction Gigabit Server
 Adapter" just by using/passing the Ethernet name "XC99HT"

Comment: You could always execute an ipconfig command and then read the output with a regex, but I'm not about to write the code for you ;-)  (I hope someone gives you a better answer than that)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.name.aspx)?

```
public static void ShowInterfaceSummary()
```

{

```
NetworkInterface[] interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in interfaces)
{                
    Console.WriteLine ("Name: {0}", adapter.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(adapter.Description);
    Console.WriteLine(String.Empty.PadLeft(adapter.Description.Length,'='));
    Console.WriteLine("  Interface type .......................... : {0}", adapter.NetworkInterfaceType);
    Console.WriteLine("  Operational status ...................... : {0}", 
        adapter.OperationalStatus);
    string versions ="";

    // Create a display string for the supported IP versions.
    if (adapter.Supports(NetworkInterfaceComponent.IPv4))
    {
         versions = "IPv4";
     }
    if (adapter.Supports(NetworkInterfaceComponent.IPv6))
    {
        if (versions.Length > 0)
        {
            versions += " ";
         }
        versions += "IPv6";
    }
    Console.WriteLine("  IP version .............................. : {0}", versions);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
Console.WriteLine();
```

}

Answer (score 1):

To do this properly from within code, you'll probably want to use WMI. WMI (Windows Management Intrumentation) is a "metadatabase" within Windows that contains information about just about everything that's going on at a device level. You access it using the System.Management namespace in .NET, primarily the ManagementObjectSearcher class. You search WMI using a syntax similar to SQL. Here's a basic query that returns all active network adapters:

```
select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration where IPEnabled = true
```

Pretty much anything you could see using IPConfig (and more) is available from the resulting ManagementObjectCollection. Unfortunately I don't know what field of the objects would have the data "XC99HT".